# Is there a way to send messages to every client connected to the same subscriber on google pubsub?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a topic with one subscription on pubsub. Each instance of my nodejs server listens to the subscription. Whenever there is a message, if it is delivered to any one of the server instances, the other instances do not receive it. Is there a way to make each instance receive the message?

Or will I have to create separate subscription for each instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want every instance of a server to receive the message, then you need to use separate subscriptions. There are two forms of having multiple subscribers:

1. Single subscription, multiple subscribers: this is *load balancing*, where messages are delivered to one of the subscribers (though duplicates can happen on occasion as Google Cloud Pub/Sub has at-least-once delivery). Use this mechanism when you need multiple subscribers to handle the throughput of messages.
2. Multiple subscriptions, one subscriber per subscription: this is *fan out*, where messages are delivered to all of the subscribers because they each have their own subscription. Use this mechanism when you need each subscriber to receive and process every message.